# Why redirect in UNIX bash script loses prints

Tags: c, bash, unix

I have a simple bash script that executes a program and redirects every input from file and redirects every output at the stdout into a file.

When i execute that without the stdout redirection it prints in the terminal every single printf of my program in correct order. When I put the redirection of the stdout then it seems to lose some of them and creates a mess with the order of them.

```
#!/bin/bash
./myprog < commands > scriptOUT.txt
```

where myprog is the executable of a program commands is a file with the input that this programm will need for an execution and scriptOUT.txt is the file that is going to be created with all the stdout at the end (That simply never happens)

Why is this happening? And is there a way around it?

Comment: Could it be that some of those are sent to STDERR and not STDOUT?

Comment: Does `./myprog` use threads?

Comment: It print's only once in STDERR. No it doesn't use threads.

Answer (score 1):

Is some of your output going to `stderr` as well as `stdout`?  Try using `>&` to redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` and see if that helps:

```
#!/bin/bash
./myprog < commands >& scriptOUT.txt
```

Comment: are you sure it's `>&`? it is `&>` as far as I know

Comment: It can be `>&` or `&>`; I believe the Bash manual recommends `&>`.

Comment: Either way it doesn't make any difference at all.